# Need same callback in ios as "ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" in android

Tags: android, iphone, ios, reachability

I am new to ios development. I want callback when connectivity change (or ip address of device is changed). I have added [Reachability (sample code of Apple)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) in my application. But it does not give callback.

I have done same thing in Android - receiving "ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" which detects a change in network connectivity has occurred.

Is there any API available in iOS which can do similar functionality as CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback):

```
Boolean SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback (
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef target,
   SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack callout,
   SCNetworkReachabilityContext *context
);
```

So your callback method will look like this

```
typedef void (*SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack) (
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef target,
   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags,
   void *info
);
```

meaning you first declare the callback

```
static void MyReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info)
{
 // do somthing
}
```

and then register it:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext ctx = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, MyReachabilityCallback, &ctx)) {
 // registered callback
```

Comment: This is Reachability code, which I have already implemented. But "MyReachabilityCallback" is not called every times when I change connectivity.

Comment: As I said Rechability code is already added to my application. But I have notice that when app goes in background and after some time it goes in suspended state. Not every time but it is random. When app is suspended, callback is not received, but I guess this reason for its behavior.Anyway thanks a lot for help.